# Automatically Authenticate with Web Application from React Native webView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aws-amplify, react-native-webview

I'm building an app using react native , in that app I want to access web application using  react-native-webview. Each time requires sign in to log in to web application. For authentication im using amplify . Is it possible to connect the web application through an auto login? because for both react and react native using same amplify configure user pool id

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set localStorage webview a token

> let setLocalStorage = `(function(){  window.localStorage.setItem('token', '${accessToken}'); })();`;

in webview use this

> injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={setLocalStorage}